# Using CanCanCan - I am clearly doing something obviously wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

Good evening,

CanCanCan is great; however, I think I am missing something incredibly obvious, as my Model logic is pretty straight forward.

- A signed-in user *who produced the thing* should be able to Read, Update & Delete
- If a signed-in user *not the thing author* should be able to Read & Comment on the thing.
- Someone not signed in should be able to read and/or search.

Steps 1 and 3 work. However, step 2 is not working - if another user is signed-in, tries to look at a thing; they see "CanCan::AccessDenied" unless it is their thing.

Ability.rb

```
    if user.present?
      can :manage, List, user_id: user.id 
    else
      can [:read, :search], List 
    end
```

Is `user.present?` linked/locked to current_user in the above snippet? I've tried omitting .present? However, that still renders CanCan::AccessDenied.

Upon this unexpected error, I thought something like the below would work, alas not.

```
    if user.present? 
      can :manage, List, user_id: user.id 
    elsif @list.find(params[:id]).user != user
      can [:read], List
    else
      can [:read, :search], List 
    end
```

For posterity please find my solution building on top of what Roman Alekseiev provided.

application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    load_and_authorize_resource :parent
    load_and_authorize_resource :child, through: :parent
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= ::User.new

    if user.new_record?
      can [:read, :search], Parent
      can [:read], Child
    else
      can [:read, :search], ::Parent
      can [:read, :create, :delete], Child
      can :manage, Parent, user_id: user.id
    end
end
```

How to use the ability in a view, for example show.

```
<% if can? :create, @parent => Child %>
present the child markup/content
<% end %>
```

[More Reading via the official documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Nested-Resources#has_many-through-associations)

Comment: You might not need cancan for this. In your ListController you could do `current_user.lists.where(id: params[:id])`

Comment: @Sunny many thanks for your comment - I think I have a number of places where that snippet is applicable. I've stuck with cancancan for other work beyond this thread. Have a smashing day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view:

```rb
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= ::User.new

    if user.new_record?
      can [:read, :search] ::List
    else
      can [:read, :comment], ::List
      can :manage, ::List, user_id: user.id
    end
```

Tried with this article, [source](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence)